Negative exponent in plot in Julia
I have data with very small values
A =[1.1222557035765826e-7, 2.651246968143401e-7, 1.7965534845544633e-7, 6.726776330241659e-7, 1.3723877581050262e-7, 2.392303846597451e-7, 1.7973640211865906e-7, 6.872377806439872e-7, 1.6561887217935582e-7, 6.478555982586488e-7, 2.8740164125831344e-8, 1.3134595362998213e-8, 7.246216395795657e-7, 5.546199071784553e-7, 7.228658562485518e-7, 3.0842483138432094e-8, 1.6105574416294378e-8, 7.601753721421415e-7];

My problem is that when I plot it, I have the issue the negative exponent is not presented correctly.
using Plots
using Printf
using ColorSchemes
using Serialization
using LaTeXStrings

aplot = plot();
plot!(aplot, dt*(1:nTimeSteps), ϵHTrunc_t_max, label=L"\Omega = %$OMEGA, \, \textrm{max. err.}") 
savefig(aplot, OUTPUT_PATH * FILES * "_H_trunc_err_t.pdf")



this means your font is "missing" the superscript negative sign. Can you switch to a different font?

@kirklong many thanks for the answer! Which one should I try out? I did try for different fonts actually...

isn't that TeX rendering?
